# Can I list files from a folder sorted by date modified?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found this code, but list file names sorted by name and I don't know how to adapt it:

```
Dim MyPathAs String
Dim MyNameAs String

 With Dialogs(wdDialogCopyFile)
 If .Display() <> -1 Then Exit Sub
  MyPath = .Directory
 End With

If Len(MyPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
 If Asc(MyPath) = 34 Then
 MyPath = Mid$(MyPath, 2, Len(MyPath) - 2)
End If

MyName = Dir$(MyPath& "*.*")
Do While MyName<> ""
Selection.InsertAfterMyName&vbCr
MyName = Dir
Loop
 Selection.CollapsewdCollapseEnd

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different way to do it. In Word VBA editor:

Tools > References... > checkmark both of:

- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Excel Object Library

Then:

```
Dim iFil As Long
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File
Dim fld As Folder
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngTableTopLeft As Excel.Range

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set sh = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
Set rngTableTopLeft = sh.Range("A1") ' or wherever; doesn't matter

'Put file names and date last modified in Excel sheet
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set fld = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\jeacor\Documents")
For Each fil In fld.Files
    iFil = iFil + 1
    With rngTableTopLeft.Cells(iFil, 1)
        .Value = fil.Name
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = fil.DateLastModified
    End With
Next fil
'Sort them by date last modified using Excel Sort function
With sh.Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=rngTableTopLeft.Offset(0, 1).Resize(fld.Files.Count, 1), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange rngTableTopLeft.Resize(fld.Files.Count, 2)
    .Apply
End With

'Copy result to Word document
With rngTableTopLeft.Resize(fld.Files.Count, 2)
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Copy
End With
Selection.Paste

'Goodbye
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'suppress the "exit without saving?" prompt
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: Hi, Jean, i need this code in Word, because in real case, my code has others funcionalities!

Comment: Right, I hadn't noticed the Word tag. Modified answer to copy resulting table from Excel to Word.